# how to create a maze with curved walls

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I am trying to build a maze similar to the one shown below.

[image: maze]

This was made with basic urdf models on pybullet physics simulator. However, if you look at it closely, some pair of walls have gaps in between them and some don't. I tried many ways to get rid of them but it's very inconsistent for some reason. Instead I'd like to make the same shape on blender as a single .obj file. Any links or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want thet two maze walls touching you could do this in object mode without the need to edit anything.

With a default scene resize the cube as required

[image]

when finished <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and reset all of the transforms

[image]

Turn on snapping and set snapping to vertex

[image]

Select the 3D cursor and snap as shown

[image]

with the cube selected <kbd>right</kbd><kbd>click</kbd> and choose origin to 3D cursor

[image]

With the cube selected press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to make a copy and immediately <kbd>right</kbd><kbd>click</kbd>. This makes a copy and leaves it in place.

Select one of the cubes and <kbd>F3</kbd> and type Mirror and choose the X axis

[image]

[image]

<kbd>r</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>22.5</kbd> to rotate the object 22.5 degrees

and then the same with the other cube but use -22.5

[image]

You now have the shape and can copy and rotate as required.

Comment: This got it to work! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Create the following shape using NURBS curves. Then convert it to mesh, solidify and use array modifier.

[image]